# Broadcast Receiver not receiving

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I know this question comes here fairly often, but I've looked through probably 20 stack overflow questions already and haven't been able to find a solution. I'm fairly certain it's something simple I'm doing wrong but I'm pretty new to Android and this assignment is due in 7 hours or so.

Everything works up until the receiver being called. Here's the call, from a service

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.WatchReceiver.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra(CHANGEKEY, changedURLs);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Now here's the receiver, nested inside the main activity

```
public class WatchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(null, "broadcast received");
        markAsChanged(intent.getStringArrayListExtra(WatchService.CHANGEKEY));
    }
}
```

And the main activity's on start function, where I register the receiver

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    wr = new WatchReceiver();
    markedAsChanged = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(wr, new IntentFilter());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WatchService.class);
    sc = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            wb = (WatchService.WatchBinder) service;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            wb = null;
        }
    };
    bindService(intent, sc, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit `Intents` do not work with `registerReceiver()`, whether you are calling `registerReceiver()` on a `Context` (for system-level broadcasts) or on an instance of `LocalBroadcastManager` (for local broadcasts).

Instead:

- Define an action string (e.g., `final String ACTION="com.dellosa.nick.ITS_HUMP_DAY";`)
- Use that action string when creating the `Intent` to broadcast (`new Intent(ACTION)`)
- Use that action string when creating the `IntentFilter` (`new IntentFilter(ACTION)`)